# Multi-Dimensional Graphing Libraries for Java

Tags: java, graphics, data-visualization, multidimensional-array

I have been working on projects that deal with 2-Dimensional graphing, UML diagramming and relational graphing (node-link diagrams). I am interested in moving to projects that deal more with 3-Dimensional graphing of scatter plots and 3-Dimensional navigation. Could someone suggest a few books, or libraries that would help me get started?

**EDIT:** I don't think I was very clear in my question. The focus of my work is information and scientific visualization so I need something that is not only good for drawing but also for visualizing data.

Comment: Google, for a start: http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/java3d/

Comment: java3d isn't being maintained anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JOGL](http://kenai.com/projects/jogl/pages/Home) (Java Open GL) is the standard 3d library for java. The OpenGL "[Red Book](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/red_book/)" is the standard Book for Open GL programming.

I dunno if there are any good packages for doing 3d plotting out of the box, though.

Comment: I just started looking at OpenGl and it seems like it would be good for drawing but would it be effective for data visualization?

Comment: You might need to write the visualization code yourself. It's not that hard.

Comment: I think I might use JMathPlot for scientific information and OpenGL for everything else. Thank you for the suggestions

Answer (score 2):

How about using one of the Java frontends for GNUplot?

- [classes for producing plots with the Unix/Linux gnuplot tool](http://www.is.informatik.uni-duisburg.de/projects/java-unidu/api/de/unidu/is/gnuplot/package-summary.html)
- [JavaPlot](http://gnujavaplot.sourceforge.net/JavaPlot/About.html)
- [jgnuplot](http://jgnuplot.sourceforge.net/)

Another possibility would be to use the [Java/R interface](http://www.rforge.net/JRI/) and let R do the heavy lifting inside your Java app.

One last option is [JMathPlot](http://jmathtools.berlios.de/doku.php?id=jmathplot:tutorial).

Comment: I looked into using JMathPlot and I like it alot. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

[JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) is a very good graphing library for Java.

Comment: JFreeChart is one of the graphing libraries I use for 2D graphs, however; I don't think it can be used for 3D graphing.

Answer (score 0):

How about the 3D functionality of [processing](http://processing.org/)? Or is that too generic for your needs?

Comment: I always had the impression that http://processing.org was only used for prototyping and not for robust applications. Is this the case?

Comment: The point of processing is that it allows anyone to get a quick visual feedback based on their scripts which allows people to prototype their crazy ideas such as "Hey, what if I multiply sin curve with tanh!?" That means it's good/great for prototyping but it's not the only thing it can do.

Comment: I think processing is suitable for production use. It might be too generic for your specific use though. I doesn't have easy "plot3d" like commands such as gnuplot, R or matlab

Answer (score 0):

[MathGL](http://mathgl.sf.net/) is GPL plotting library (can plot 2- and 3-ranged data) and in principle it may have Java interface (using SWIG). But I never test it since I'm not familiar with Java :(

Answer (score 0):

Try my open source 2D/3D java graphing library, DataDisplay. Any feedback you can give would be just swell.

https://sourceforge.net/p/msu-doe-dd/